# DBF file is not a valid Path - VBA

Tags: vba, dbf

I'm trying to make a connection with a dbf file trough Visual Basic, i'm using the following connection string:

dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\joelgjunior\Desktop\PROVISAOMAT_012020.dbf";Persist Security Info=False;

The connection string seems correct, but the code can't recognize the dbf file i don't know why, the name and the path are written correctly but the vb always say that is not a valid path, otherwise i did it to an accdb file and it worked. Can someone help me in this case? Thanks

Comment: You need to escape the quotes in the DataSource like this `Data Source=""C:\Users\joelgjunior\Desktop\PROVISAOMAT_012020.dbf"";`.

Comment: I tried this but still the same error message.

Comment: Try getting rid of the quotes completely.  See [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/).

Comment: The problem is in the dbf file, the system don't recognize it, but when i use accdb extension files it always work correctly

Comment: Your connection string is likely using the wrong Provider.  Try the `Jet` Provider.  Visit the link I provided for details.

Comment: I tried Jet Provider but i got the message "Provider not Found"

Answer (score 0):

A connection string points to the PATH where the data files are located.  Then, any .dbf within that path location (or child-folder within) is accessible.

Think of it this way.  A normal SQL command might be

```
select * from PROVISAOMAT_012020 where...
```

The SQLCommand object uses the CONNECTION to point to the location.  So if the connection has the dbf name as well, your query will basically be interpreted as

```
select * from C:\Users\joelgjunior\Desktop\PROVISAOMAT_012020.dbf\PROVISAOMAT_012020 where...
```

Also, if using .DBF files, is it dBASE, or Visual FoxPro (VFP), if VFP, I would download those drivers and use them instead of ACE.